# Finding the specific Turn Ratio of a Transformer

Tags: transformer, ac

I'm finding the turn ratio for a Hammond 166G28 28VCT transformer. I already had calculated the voltages for the Primary and for the Secondary and I divided them and got 3:1 ratio for the outer loop (Green to Green).
Where can I find this turn ratio from the transformer's specification sheet or from any other source so I can verify my findings?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find that the transformer is rated 115 V, 60 Hz for the primary and 28 V secondary. That gives a nominal turns ratio of 115/28 = 4.1:1. The actual ratio used may be slightly different to make the secondary voltage 28 volts at a particular load current and operating temperature. Transformer specifications usually state only the operating specifications, not the design specifications. You probably will not find more than what is easily available.